# CASE...WHEN in WHERE clause in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE t1.id_status_notatka_1 = ANY (selected_type)  
 AND t1.id_status_notatka_2 = ANY (selected_place)
```

here I would like to add CASE WHEN 
so my query is:

```
    SELECT *  
    FROM table 
    WHERE t1.id_status_notatka_1 = ANY (selected_type)  
      AND t1.id_status_notatka_2    = ANY (selected_place) 
      AND CASE 
            WHEN t2.id_bank = 12 THEN t1.id_status_notatka_4 = ANY (selected_effect) 
         END
```

but it doesn't work. The syntax is good but it fails in searching for anything. So my question is - how use CASE WHEN in WHERE clause. Short example: if a=0 then add some condition to WHERE (AND condition), if it's not then don't add (AND condition)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No need for `CASE EXPRESSION` , simply use `OR` with parenthesis :

```
AND (t2.id_bank <> 12 OR t1.id_status_notatka_4 = ANY (selected_effect))
```

Answer (score 36):

For those looking to use a CASE in the WHERE clause, in the above adding an `else true` condition in the case block should allow the query to work as expected.  In the OP, the case will resolve as NULL, which will result in the WHERE clause effectively selecting WHERE ... AND NULL, which will always fail.

```
SELECT *  
FROM table 
WHERE t1.id_status_notatka_1 = ANY (selected_type)  
  AND t1.id_status_notatka_2    = ANY (selected_place) 
  AND CASE 
        WHEN t2.id_bank = 12 THEN t1.id_status_notatka_4 = ANY (selected_effect)
        ELSE true 
     END
```

Comment: Actually answers the question in the title!

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer works, but I'd like to share input for those who are looking for a different answer. Thanks to sagi, I've come up with the following query, but I'd like to give a test case as well.

Let us assume this is the structure of our table

```
tbl
id   | type     | status
-----------------------
1    | Student  | t
2    | Employee | f
3    | Employee | t
4    | Student  | f
```

and we want to select all Student rows, that have Status = 't', however, We also like to retrieve all Employee rows regardless of its Status.

if we perform `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE type = 'Student' AND status = 't'` we would only get the following result, we won't be able to fetch Employees

```
tbl
id   | type     | status
-----------------------
1    | Student  | t
```

and performing `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Status = 't'` we would only get the following result, we got an Employee Row on the result but there are Employee Rows that were not included on the result set, one could argue that performing `IN` might work, however, it will give the same result set. `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE type IN('Student', 'Employee') AND status = 't'`

```
tbl
id   | type     | status
-----------------------
1    | Student  | t
3    | Employee | t
```

remember, we want to retrieve all Employee rows regardless of its Status, to do that we perform the query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (type = 'Student' AND status = 't') OR (type = 'Employee')
```

result will be

```
table
id   | type     | status
-----------------------
1    | Student  | t
2    | Employee | f
3    | Employee | t
```