# Postgresql: CASE WHEN in WHERE-clause depending on Column type

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with several columns of different type that can be extended dynamically. Now I want to enable to create dynamic searches on every column within this table but differentiate between number and text/varchar datatypes.
The Column name **my_int_column** is dynamically added from java-code, in another query it might be **my_text_column** or **username**.

This is my query:

```
SELECT my_int_column, pg_typeof(my_int_column) as type_of_column
FROM  tablename.my_dynamic_table
WHERE my_int_column IS NOT NULL  
AND (
    CASE
       WHEN (pg_typeof(my_int_column) != 'integer'::regtype) THEN my_int_column::VARCHAR LIKE '%52%'
       ELSE LOWER(my_int_column)::VARCHAR LIKE '%52%'
    END
)
```

Unfortunately this does not work - it never reaches the ELSE and throws this error:

> ERROR:  function lower(integer) does not exist

Can somebody help me? How can I correctly compare the result of the pg_typeof() ?

I searched for other questions but only found this: [other question regarding pg_typeof in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71856993/1856258)

Comment: Why not simply `AND my_int_column::text LIKE '%52%'`?

Comment: Because I want to be able to use the same query for multi columns and the contents of the text-columns might have upper and lower case names, e.g. inserted from Excel-Import, e.g. search for the names: Smith, SMITH, smith. Or is the LIKE case insensitive? I thought not.

Comment: I see. Well, first cast to text, `AND LOWER(my_int_column::text) LIKE ...`. Still you may use `ILIKE` i.e. case insensitive like or - I prefer that - [regexp operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) `~*`

Comment: great, thanks a lot. I didn't think of casting within the lower function. Perfect.

Comment: Thanks for commeting @Stefanov.sm So I do not need an answer to my original question any more.